# Is this implementation of signed URLs reasonably secure?

Tags: c#, security, .net-core

I'm trying to implement signed URLs for short lived access to static files.
The idea is:

- generate an URL with an expiration timestamp (e.g. `https://example.com/file.png?download=false&expires=1586852158`)
- sign it with HMACSHA256 and a private key and append the signature at the end of URL (e.g. `https://example.com/file.png?download=false&expires=1586852158&signature=6635ea14baeeaaffe71333cf6c7fa1f0af9f6cd1a17abb4e75ca275dec5906d1`

When i receive the request on the server, I take out the `signature` parameter and verify that the rest of the URL signed with HMACSHA256 and the same private key results in the same signature.

The implementation is as follows:

```
    public static class URLSigner
    {
        private static string GetSignatureForUri(string uri, byte[] key)
        {
            var hmac = new HMACSHA256(key);
            var signature = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uri));
            var hexSignature = BitConverter.ToString(signature).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLowerInvariant();
            return hexSignature;
        }

        public static string SignUri(string uri, byte[] key)
        {
            var hexSignature = GetSignatureForUri(uri, key);
            return QueryHelpers.AddQueryString(uri, new Dictionary<string, string> { { "signature", hexSignature }});
        }

        public static bool VerifyUri(string uri, byte[] key)
        {
            var signatureRegex = "[\\?&]signature=([a-z0-9]+)$";
            var signatureMatch = Regex.Match(uri, signatureRegex);
            if (!signatureMatch.Success || signatureMatch.Groups.Count != 2)
                return false;
            var parsedSignature = signatureMatch.Groups[1].Value;

            var originalUri = Regex.Replace(uri, signatureRegex, "");
            var hexSignature = GetSignatureForUri(originalUri, key);
            return hexSignature == parsedSignature;
        }
    }
```

and it's used like so:

```
var signedUri = URLSigner.SignUri("https://example.com/file.png?download=false", secretKey);
var isVerified = URLSigner.VerifyUri(signedUri, secretKey);
```

The timestamp is verified separately on the request handler.

Is this implementation of signed URLs reasonably secure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a rather straightforward use of HMAC. So I would presume it is safe from that perspective.

A note about terminology. Personally I would talk about an *authentication tag* or simply *HMAC value* because people often associate signatures with asymmetric algorithms such as RSA. The same goes for "private key"; I'd use *secret key* for symmetric keys as in your code.

Some remarks:

- the regular expression is used twice, it seems more logical to match the entire GET request and make sure it ends with the *group* with the signature in it (even if that just means using `.*`);
- to remove one way of attacks, I'd make sure that there aren't *two* authentication tags in the GET request;
- to remove another, I'd include a sequence number or time stamp so that replay attacks are not possible;
- hexadecimals are not very efficient, I'd use a base64url encoder, it's made for it;
- the groups count check is unnecessary, either the regex matches or it doesn't.

One idea is to have a method split the URI and the signature, you don't need the authentication tag after verification after all - you could for instance use [a tuple](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#tuples-as-method-return-values) with the verification status and the URL without signature (as optional value), or use a yucky output parameter. Check your coding standards before doing either of these though.